# Magento 2 - How does require know where jquery is defined?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, script, requirejs-config.js

You can use jquery in phtml like this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
],function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Your logic */
     });  
 });
```

But how does the `require` know where to find `jquery`.
I searched the whole codebase, but the path to the jquery file is nowhere defined in no **requirejs-config.js** file, so how does it know where the file is located?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for defined `jquery` paths or mappings in require-js configs. Because jquery is located directly in `lib/web/jquery.js`.
As such it will be present in the `pub/static` files directly within the locale directory. `pub/static/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery.js`.

As such the path `jquery` within the require of js components or phtml is just resolved on the same way like every other path e.g. to `Magento_Catalog/js/gallery` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of composer and framework

Not been modified in a while but here for example is where the path was changed

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/98214d73ce4ab6d873786759c804b9994be82f29

Comment: I looked at the github site, but I still can't figure out, where jquery is defined so that it can be used anywhere in requirejs

Answer (score 0):

Magento framework already defined jquery at some place inside Magento Installation.
 Please go though this tutorial to know more -
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Please let me know if you still have doubts. 
For example  - Here Jquery is defined and path is given.

```
define ([
    'jquery',
    'mage/gallery/gallery'
], function ($, Gallery) {

    $(function () { // to ensure that code evaluates on page load
        $('[data-role=example]')  // we expect that page contains markup <tag data-role="example">..</tag>
            .each(function (index, element) {
                Gallery({
                    options:  {},
                    data: [{
                        img: 'https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7077/27935031965_facd03b4cb_b_d.jpg'
                    }],
                    fullscreen: {}
                }, element);  // 'element' is single DOM node.
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: "Magento framework already defined jquery at some place inside Magento Installation"
Thats my question. How does require know where jquery is located?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you don't specify a script in requirejs and still try to load it, then magento searches for a script by that name in

```
pub/static/versionXXXXXXXXXX/frontend/**themeNamespace**/**ThemeName**/**language_code**/
```

So if you try to use this script:

```
require([
    'foobar'
],function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Your logic */
     });  
 });
```

but you never defined `foobar` in requirejs-config.js, then magento tries to load it from here (example)

```
pub/static/version1617131196/frontend/company/fresh/de_DE/foobar.js
```

If you look at the files in this folder, then you notice that the `jquery.js` file is located here.

Comment: Apologies. I also thought you were also asking how does it get there from lib